# Problema com python em usar o .join

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso imprimir um endereço MAC, com separador ' : ', mas só consigo imprimir o endereço com o separador a cada casa da string, sendo que o endereço MAC separa a cada 2 casas.

Comment: talvez [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961327/4551469) ajude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você for usar `.join` então esta solução te atenderá:

```
>>> ':'.join([addr[x-2:x] for x in range(2, len(addr)+2,2)])
'0a:1b:2c:3d:4e:5f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for só para a impressão na tela, você pode tentar uma solução mais simples:

```
>>> addr='0a1b2c3d4e5f'
>>> '{0}{1}:{2}{3}:{4}{5}:{6}{7}:{8}{9}:{10}{11}'.format(*addr)
'0a:1b:2c:3d:4e:5f'
```